# Zend/Loader failed to open stream

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am following along in a book called Pro PHP from Kevin McArthur Copyright is 2008 so it is a fairly old book. So far everything has been working as intended except when I got to the Learning ZendFramework part. It is saying that the `Zend/Loader.php` file does not exist which is correct in my case. I am using version 2.2.5 while the book is using 1.0.3. I have check the Zend directory and there is a Loader directory with several files except for `loader.php`. Is there a way that I can make my version work with what is in the book easily or is it more trouble than its worth? In the book I am stuck on the following part:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
define('ZFW_VERSION', '2.2.5');
define('ZFW_PREFIX', '/usr/share/php5/ZendFramework');
define('APP_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__). '/../'));

$paths = array(
    APP_PATH,
    APP_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'application' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'models',
    ZFW_PREFIX. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'ZendFramework-' . ZFW_VERSION . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'library',
    get_include_path()
    );

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));

require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';

Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();

$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->throwExceptions(TRUE);
$front->run(APP_PATH . '/application/controllers');
```

Can I modify this code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZF1 and ZF2 are not compatible, so you won't be able to use ZF2 with a tutorial written for ZF1. If you want to stick with the book, download the latest version of ZF1 (currently 1.12.3) and use that instead. You might also need to slightly tweak the Zend Loader lines to this:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

due to some changes that were made after that book was written.

Alternatively you could learn ZF2 instead, which might be a bit more future proof.